# Copy Data in DOM Show in Popup.html In (Google Extensions)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for an onclick inside the Popup.html button, Copy website element data, and set data inside the Popup.html ID which is N/a currently.

[image]

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Copy Data in DOM",
    "description": "Extension ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,

    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
            "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
            "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
            "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
}
```

content.js

```
document.getElementById("copySecondIddata").value;
document.getElementById("copyFirstIddata").value;
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Fist Id Data: <span id="domFirstIdData">N/a</span></p>
    <p>Fist Id Data: <span id="domSecondIdData">N/a</span></p>

    <button type="button" id="setdata">Seat Data</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function idTarget() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });
};
document.getElementById("setdata").onclick = idTarget;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last expression in the executed file (or code) is automatically passed to the callback of executeScript.

content.js: removed

manifest.json:

```json
"permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"]
```

popup.js:

```js
document.getElementById('setdata').onclick = async () => {
  try {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
    const res = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      function: () => [
        document.getElementById('copyFirstIddata').value,
        document.getElementById('copySecondIddata').value,
      ],
    });
    res = res[0].result; // the first element is the main page of the tab
    document.getElementById('domFirstIddata').value = res[0];
    document.getElementById('domSecondIddata').value = res[1];
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

Comment: I don't know want happening but, this line `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'content.js'}, res => ` of code showing error " which is "Uncaught TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function " in Extension area. @wOxxOm

Comment: In ManifestV3 it's renamed so use the updated answer.